# Python rank and tuples

Tags: python, tuples, rank

What I am trying to do is read a list from a config file:

```
import re
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj('food.conf')
meal_list = config['MainConfig']['MealList']
```

The `MealList` section in the config looks like `Turkey|Hamburger|Chicken` etc etc.

After that I need to run each of them through:

```
for meal in meal_list:
    if re.search( config[meal][ingredients]['Allowlist'], badingredients, re.M|re.I):
```

Here comes my first problem. How do I join them correctly? Beacuse after this `for` part, I pass them to a rank function. So how do I join the "allowed" ones into a tuple?
The rank is also defined in the in the config file.

```
meal_allowed = ('Hamburger', 2),('Chicken', 3),('Turkey', 4)

food = sorted(meal_allowed, key=lambda student: student[1])
food_to_eat = str(food).translate(None, "-[]()'0123456789").replace(" ",      "").replace(",,",",")
print food_to_eat
```

So in short how do I use .join() and then turn it in to tuples?

#### Edit

Another example of what i am looking for.

```
meals = 'hamburger', 'Turkey', 'Chicken'
for meal in meals:
 rank = config[meal][rank]
 if re.search( config[meal][ingredients]['Allowlist'], badingredients, re.M|re.I):
  eatable = meal + meal + rank
```

eatable should be ('Hamburger', 2),('Chicken', 3),('Turkey', 4) format.
Else i cant rank it.

Comment: What is the exact output you wish to achieve? Is it a `tuple` of the `meal_allowed` or the `food_to_eat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
meal_allowed = tuple(('Hamburger', 2), ('Chicken', 3), ('Turkey', 4))
```

**Edit:**

For each `meal`:

```
meals = ['hamburger', 'Turkey', 'Chicken']
for meal in meals:
    rank = config[meal][rank]
```

You must define what is the `rank` variable in `rank = config[meal][rank]`. After this, you may build a list of tuples, like:

```
eatable = list()
meals = ['hamburger', 'Turkey', 'Chicken']
for meal in meals:
    rank = config[meal][rank]
    if re.search( config[meal][ingredients]['Allowlist'], badingredients, re.M|re.I):
        eatable.append((meal, rank))

print eatable
```

Anyway, shouldn't you say "edible" instead of "eatable"? Or they're both right? ^^

Comment: I added another example that might explain better what it is iam looking for.

Comment: I misstyped rank, it should be ['rank'] since that is a section in the  configuration file. But eatable.append((meal, rank)) is then what iam looking for.

Comment: @tsjk I've said that initial attribution was not right, but it is, actually; I didn't know, but using just commas, python converts the entries into a tuple, so `a = 'a', 'b', 'c'` is the same of `a = ('a', 'b', 'c')` or `a = tuple('a', 'b', 'c')`. Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Actully that dident work at all with the sorting function. Getting TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.  My rank code looks like this. sorted(eatable, key=eatable(1))